# IdentityServer ClaimsIdentity to Impersonated WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, kerberos-delegation

I've got an IdentityServer setup to connect to an external ADFS server. I'm able to login and obtain an access token via OAuth2 / OpenId Connect. An AspNet.Core WebApi runs within an IIS AppPool with a user that has Kerberos delegation enabled (should have, not sure how to check since I'm not into infrastructure).

What I want to achieve is that the ClaimsIdentity I get from IdentityServer on the WebApi is transformed back to a WindowsIdentity using impersonation, without a password. Just a username should be sufficient. With the actual impersonated WindowsIdentity I should then logon to a database and do some mutations.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.

I took [this](https://github.com/phibsi/sample-aspnetcore-impersonation/blob/master/Services/ImpersonationService.cs) as a base for the Impersonation implementation. The only problem I have is that the `Context.User.Identity` doesn't return a `WindowsIdentity`, but a `ClaimsIdentity`.

Another approach I tried is using `var user = new WindowsIdentity(username);` where username would be the UPN. That creates an Identity, with `ImpersonationLevel.Identity` instead of `ImpersonationLevel.Impersonated`. When I run `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated()` with this users access token will give an Access Denied, or IOException when loading the needed assemblies.

So first question: how do I check if the IIS AppPool user has the correct Kerberos delegation rights?

Second question: is it even possible to impersonate a user only with a username?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is delegation with "any" authentication method. Protocol-wise this is called Service-for-User-to-Proxy. It requires that the service account is granted that right and you need to check the Active Directory service account is configured for that. You also need to indicate which services can receive impersonated connections.

Once you've configured the service account you should restart the machine running the code (things get negatively cached in memory which takes a while to time out). If your app is running in IIS your service account should already be configured to use the correct Windows local privileges to impersonate.

However, keep in mind that this permission gives your application global permissions for whatever service you're requesting a service ticket to. That means your app can impersonate everyone, which is rightfully a little dangerous.

[image]